# C++ OpenMP: put complex variable in or before loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a loop that I want to process in parallel. Each thread needs an (independent) chunk of memory, but it can be overwritten in every iteration and needn't be reallocated. See the following example:

```
vector<int> scratch(size);
for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    f(arguments, scratch);
    g(scratch);
}
```

where `f` takes `scratch` as an output parameter. To make this parallelizable, I could do

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    vector<int> scratch(size);
    f(arguments, scratch);
    g(scratch);
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    vector<int> scratch(size);
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
        f(arguments, scratch);
        g(scratch);
    }
}
```

Will I be wasting time for constructing and deconstructing `scratch` in the first version? Or will the compiler (with optimization) most likely reuse the memory and refrain from reallocation?

Comment: If you can guarantee threads will only read/write from their own portion of the vector you don't need to allocate seperate vectors or even read/write protection (std::mutex) on the data. And maybe you don't even need to use openmp (std::for_each with  std::execution::par). It would help to know more about what you're trying to do and how memory is accessed. Maybe you need to have a shared read_copy and multiple partial output vectors hard to say from your example. (And in multithreading scenarios, details matter... a lot)

Comment: If your parallel region is going to be execute only once: who cares about the cost. If it's going to be executed multiple times: the C++ runtime will reuse the space for those vectors, so don't worry. Btw, I disagree with @PepijnKramer about using the C++ parallel mechanism: you can not tell those to bind threads to cores so your cache behavior may be very much worse.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Good points :) I usually go for native C++ features first, and only optimize further when requirements require it.  (I have to take into account that software will be maintaied by a lot of, potentially not so experienced, engineers  and then standard C++ helps).

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I wouldn't have thought that the C++ runtime could avoid allocations like that. One could also use `std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource` to explicitly avoid allocations.

Comment: The second solution is better, but without knowing the details of `f` and `g` functions it is not possible to tell if it will result in a noticeable speed difference. My suggestion is to measure it in your case.

Comment: @paleonix The C++ runtime keeps a free list. So if you allocate, free, and reallocate with the same size, it will find that block extremely quickly.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Fast modern allocators nearly always use a bucket/arena strategy (some of them combine this with a thread-local storage cache so to scale better but not perfectly because of possible tricky patterns like producers/consumers) for relatively small sizes. For bigger ones, they often fallback to the allocator of the OS (which often uses free-lists for relatively large allocations). Still, this is fast (in fact, even faster than free-lists) assuming `f` and `g` are not very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

On a mainstream PC, **the second code is inefficient**. Indeed, it generally code the vector to be reallocated and filled with zeros for every iterations. Regarding your system, **the default allocator may not scale** (AFAIK it is typically the case on Windows with MSVC, but it should be fine on Linux with Jemalloc) and this will reduce the performance of your application. The eager **zeros-based vector filling** can also causes the same issue if `size` is big since the *RAM is a limited shared resource*. Compilers like Clang are able to optimize out some allocations, but in this case, [neither GCC nor Clang are able to do this optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/5f4x946dK) (and the overhead of the `memset` would still be present anyway).

The third example is quite efficient since the array is allocated and filled only once. Each thread has its own vector so the **locality** is good. This solution is only worst than the first if the number of iteration is smaller than the number of thread. However, this is not much an issue since it is inefficient in both cases anyway if the `f` and `g` calls are short (because of the overhead to distribute the work between threads) or the overhead of the vector is negligible in both cases if the `f` and `g` calls are long.